Interpretation of an anticorrelation between $H_0$ and $\log_{10}(\omega_{BD})$ with Brans-Dicke's theory in a triplot diagram
I get below the following contours of a MCMC run with the main cosmological parameters for Brans-Dickce's theory without introducing a cosmological constant ($\Lambda=0$) and considering only baryonic matter component.

Could you justify the anticorrelation that I get between $H_0$ and $\omega_{BD}$ (actually $\log10(\omega_{BD}$) ?
If we take the relation :
$\Omega_{B D}=\frac{\omega_{B D}}{6}\left(\frac{F_0}{H_0}\right)^2-\frac{F_0}{H_0} $, then I can express $H_0$ as a function of $\omega_{BD}$ :
$H_0=\frac{-F_0+\sqrt{F_0^2+\frac{2 \Omega_{B D \omega_{B D} F_0^2}}{3}}}{2 \Omega_{B D}} .$
From this relation, we are expected to have a correlation instead of an anti-correlation since if $\omega_{BD}$ increases, then, $H_0$ will increase.
If someone could help me to justify my result (if it is true), this would be great.
Solution : the above demonstration is false. The true one is :
\begin{aligned}
& \Omega=\frac{\omega}{6}\left(\frac{F}{H}\right)^2-\frac{F}{H} \\
& \frac{E}{H}=A \\
& \Omega=\frac{\omega}{6} A^2-A \\
& \frac{\omega}{6} A^2-A-\Omega=0 \\
& A_{1 / 2}=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1+\frac{4 \omega \Omega}{6}}}{2}, A>0 \\
& \frac{F}{H}=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+\frac{4 \omega \Omega}{6}}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{4+\frac{\omega \Omega}{6}} \\
& H=\frac{F}{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{4+\frac{\omega \Omega}{6}}}
\end{aligned}
such that when $\omega_{BD}$ increases, $H_0$ decreases, so the anticorrelation is present.
